# Discontinuity preserving filter

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Is there a filter in MATLAB that preserves discontinuity in an image, as in the first part of mean shift segmentation algorithm? If there isn't, then how can I design a kernel to do such a filtering?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "preserves". All non-trivial linear filters will have some effect on edges (or the neighbourhood).

Comment: do you mean `edge-preserving filter?`

Comment: Yes, I believe it means that. I am actually trying to do segmentation of an image using mean shift algorithm. The algorithm says do a discontinuity preserving filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to this [report](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~zjwinner/SIP_note/Mean%20Shift%20%20Segmentation.pdf), the specific values for sizes of spatial-domain and range-domain kernel window `hs` and `hr` facilitates the continuity preserving filtering in mean shift. As you select the kernel function with the form of `k(|yk-xi|^2/h^2)` where `k` is usually represented by a Gaussian function, for each pixel xi in the image, you iteratively compute `yk` with the formula (8).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i was referring to. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Anisotropic Diffusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropic_diffusion), a.k.a. Perona–Malik diffusion.  There is a [MATLAB code on FEX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14995-anisotropic-diffusion-perona-malik). It performs smoothing, while preserving large intensity gradients (e.g. edges).

There is another implementation [here](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/#anisodiff).

Another idea is the bilateral filter [[implementation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36657-fast-bilateral-filter)].

Comment: Better than bilteral filter - guided filter. [Project webpage](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/kahe/eccv10/).

Comment: @Parag A good suggestion. You're welcome to edit the post, although I think lennon310 followed the comments to the true intention of the OP, which actually seems to prescribe a somewhat primitive method by comparison... Still, this QA seems a decent enough place to list some edge-preserving filtering algorithms with MATLAB implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at an advanced Anisotropic Non Linear Diffusion Filter:

https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Fast-Anisotropic-Curvature-Preserving-Smoothing

This is the best Diffusion based filter to my knowledge.

P.S.
Be happy if people assist keep developing it.